# How do I fix "The name 'X' is not permitted in this context"?

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO dbo.VehiclesCategories ( VehicleId, CategoryId )
VALUES ( t1.ID , t2.ID)

SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID
FROM dbo.Vehicle t1
inner JOIN dbo.VehicleCategory t2 ON t1.Category = t2.Name
```

In the above SQL, I want to insert two values into a M:M join table. The SELECT statement works fine and I get the desired results. The INSERT statement throws the following error:

```
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
The name "t1.ID" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

How do I insert the two values (t1.ID and t2.ID) into the table?

Comment: Guess I've become a casualty of a drive-by downvoter... Explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because in the context of the INSERT, `t1` and `t2`, don't exist.

If you combine those two queries, I think it will do exactly what you want:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.VehiclesCategories ( VehicleId, CategoryId )
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID
FROM dbo.Vehicle t1
inner JOIN dbo.VehicleCategory t2 ON t1.Category = t2.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not include the `VALUES (t1.ID, t2.ID)` part at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT dbo.VehiclesCategories ( VehicleId, CategoryId )  
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID 
FROM dbo.Vehicle t1 
JOIN dbo.VehicleCategory t2 ON t1.Category = t2.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete `VALUES ( t1.ID , t2.ID)` from `insert into`